# SQL table search

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and was just wondering how I would a value from a table only when it meets a certain condition.

I have a table that looks like the following (sorry for the rubbish formatting)

```
COL1 - COL2

 1   -  3  
 1   -  2 
 2   -  2
 3   -  3
 3   -  4
```

I want to get values from COL1, but only if they don't have a specific value in COL2.

So for example if I didn't want the values where COL2 was 3, the only value that would be returned from COL1 would be 2.

Thanks for any help

To clarify, the two columns just store id's that reference other tables. I only want the values from COL1 that don't reference a specific values in COL2.

so when I saw I don't want the values where COL2 is equal to 3, this means the value '1' from COL1 won't be returned as on row 1 COL2 is 3 and 3 won't be returned from COL1 because on row4 COL2 is equal to 3

Comment: "So for example if I didn't want the values where COL2 was 3, the only value that would be returned from COL1 would be 2." - not according to the sample data you posted.

Comment: 2 is also there in given example ... row no 3....
please check and edit your question that whether you want 1 from col1

Comment: Your question makes no sense with the sample data you have provided, hence the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you look for something like this.

```
select COL1
from TABLE_FOO
where  COL1 not in (
  select COL1
  from TABLE_FOO
  where COL2 = 3
)
```

Comment: I guess you are the only one smart enough what that question was supposed to tell us ;) 1+

Comment: great job... after seeing your answer only it is clear what is the question... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot bw_üezi that did the trick :) sorry to everyone else for the question being a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think Specific value means the record having only one corresponding value in the col2.
2-2 is specific because it has a specific value.

select col1 from c group by col1 having count(col2) > 1

The above query gives all the col1 values which does not have a specific values.